# Does bubbly froth mean my vinegar batch needs trashed?

Tags: fermentation, spoilage

I have been making apple cider vinegar at home for a while now. My current batch has white powdery, bubbly froth forming on the top of the bottle and some powder at the bottom. What should I do?

I have sifted all my bottles through thick cloth and re-bottled. I don't see any scummy mother forming. Should I wait longer or should I throw it away? I don't want to do that.

Please help me find a solution. It's been in the process for 8 weeks now.

Comment: Hi Fazila, welcome to Seasoned Advice! I have touched up your formatting and re-wrote the title of your question in hopes that it will get some more attention. Making ACV sounds like a cool project.

Answer (score 1):

The foam on top could mean that it is still fermenting... (converting sugar to alcohol.  The alcohol eventually turns to acid. the white powder could be "cream of tarter".  It is actually just crystallized acid.  As for the stuff on the bottom, that is just the spent yeast.